# CVS login and logout

Tags: cvs

I want to know more about how CVS login and logout work. Do they create/delete any file? if yes, which are those files? I could not find anything under CVS folders. Are these commands only valid for pserver mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in the [CVS documentation](http://www.manpagez.com/info/cvs/cvs_31.php), which should also be available via `info cvs` on your system:

> The records are stored, by default, in the file ‘`$HOME/.cvspass`’. That
>   file's format is human-readable, and to a degree human-editable, but
>   note that the passwords are not stored in cleartext—they are trivially
>   encoded to protect them from "innocent" compromise (i.e., inadvertent
>   viewing by a system administrator or other non-malicious person).
>
> You can change the default location of this file by setting the
>   `CVS_PASSFILE` environment variable. If you use this variable, make
>   sure you set it before `cvs login` is run. If you were to set it after
>   running `cvs login`, then later CVS commands would be unable to look
>   up the password for transmission to the server.

[...]

> The password for a given remote repository can be removed from the
>   CVS_PASSFILE by using the `cvs logout` command.